# Subsets of a set, S with 5 elements

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

If a set, S has 5 elements, how many subsets with three elements does that set have?

I am new to set theory, and I do not know a way to mathematically exhausting all of the possibilities.

Comment: Naturally this a well-studied problem. It falls under the heading of "permutations and combinations".

Comment: Just $\binom{5}{3}$

Comment: what does that mean

Comment: The numbers here are small enough that you can just list all the $3$-element subsets of, say, $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and then count them.

Comment: @johnknox   $\binom{5}{3}$ is read as "five choose three" which is the number of unordered ways to choose 3 elements from a set of 5. $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k! \cdot (n-k)!}$. Google "Binomial Coefficient"

Answer (score 1):

List them all out, do you see any other way to make a subset of $S$ with 3 elements in it?

{1,2,3}, {1,2,4}, {1,2,5}, {1,3,4}, {1,3,5}, {1,4,5}, {2,3,4}, {2,3,5}, {2,4,5}, {3,4,5}